# How to un-blur the image text on hover using css

Tags: css

I have an image tag in my html and below is my html element when user logins into the application it becomes blur but if user hovers on that i need to unblur it and display the text which is present in that image.How can i do this?

what i tried?

```css
img {
  transition: 0.25s filter linear;
  -webkit-transition: 0.25s filter linear;
  -moz-transition: 0.25s filter linear;
  -o-transition: 0.25s filter linear;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300" width="109" height="19" style="vertical-align:top;" border="0">
```

but its not working

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried? Where is your code? Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: where is the blur related code ?

Comment: Text cannot be *inside an image*  from the HTML perspective.

Comment: You've had several perfectly sensible answers so far and keep replying that they don't do what you want. Can you give full details of your actual question, like why you can't use a class in your HTML, how you're implementing the blur right now, and perhaps a JSFiddle so folk can see the issue in action and test solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `class` attribute on your `<img>` element that has a [:hover pseudo-selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp) like this:

```css
.blurred {
  opacity: .5;
}

.blurred:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

This results in the element having half the opacity initially and on hover it will have it's full opacity restored.

`<img class="blurred" ...otherAttrs>`

Comment: I should not use classes i need to apply directly to html element only

Comment: Maybe I don't fully understand the question, so you have an image that is blurred when the user logins, and on hover it becomes fully visible?

Comment: yes but i had tried your code on hover its not becoming unblur still it is blured

Answer (score 0):

Just set the blur value to 0px

**EDIT**

I think you should use class or id like this

```
<!-- added id attribute -->
<img src="https://realview/view-contact-number.gif" width="109" height="19" id="blur" border="0">

#blur {
    vertical-align: top;
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
}

#blur:hover {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont clearly state how you achived the blur in your question, but assuming you used `filter: blur()`, then this will do the trick:

- Your normal `img` tag should haver `filter: blur(Xpx);` applied
- When hovering (`img:hover`) you just apply a blur of 0 (`filter: blur(0);`)

```css
img {
  transition: 0.25s filter linear;
  -webkit-transition: 0.25s filter linear;
  -moz-transition: 0.25s filter linear;
  -o-transition: 0.25s filter linear;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  filter: blur(8px);
}

img:hover{
filter: blur(0);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300" width="500" height="200" style="vertical-align:top;" border="0">
```

Comment: remaining images which are blured are getting unblured on hover but that particular image is still blur

Comment: blur is not being used anywhere in my css

Comment: there is only one image in your question. It is very unclear to me what exactly you are trying to achieve... How do you blur your images? Where are your other images? etc...